# Is the Dark Knight trilogy part of the same "DC Cinematic Universe" as Man of Steel and Batman vs Superman?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, dc-extended-universe

Title pretty much says it all.

As far as I can recall Batman vs Superman did not make any specific references to events in the Dark Knight trilogy that would confirm this, and the director and lead actor are obviously different. But that trilogy was trying to be dark and gritty much like the newest DC movies, and I also can't think of anything that clearly rules out the possibility of them being in the same universe.

Do we know for sure whether these movies are meant to be in the same universe or not?

Comment: There are several connections, not least a crossover cameo; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1AXidnUv7kU&feature=youtu.be&t=1m38s

Comment: Realistic? You think Man of Steel and Superman v Batman were going for realistic??

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I...think I'll just replace that word with "gritty". I've heard some Marvel vs DC comparisons that claimed (to me plausibly) that the DC movies are trying to be darker and a tad more realistic than the Marvel ones, but attempting to weasel that in here is probably just a distraction from the main question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Snyder has said that it is a different Batman than the one from the Nolan movies.

From an interview with [The Daily Beast](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2015/09/10/zack-snyder-sorry-marvel-batman-v-superman-transcends-superhero-movies.html)

> Only in that because **it’s a different Batman than the Batman that was in the Chris Nolan movies,** so we have a little bit more explaining to do—and you just had a whole Superman movie. But I think only in that way, because you need to understand where Batman is with everything. And that’s more toward the beginning, but it evens back out as it goes on.

Snyder also said that he tried to *emulate* the universe Nolan created.

> “It’s a tricky process, setting up the DC universe, or Justice League,” Snyder said. “The credit goes to [Batman Begins director] Chris Nolan because he set the die for the DC Universe in a great way that I tried to emulate. I look at it as more being mythological than, say, bubblegum. And I think that that’s appropriate for Batman and Superman because they’re the most mythological of our superheroes.”

Less canonically, Christian Bale told [IGN](http://www.ign.com/articles/2014/12/05/christian-bale-our-batman-doesnt-belong-in-any-other-movie) that the Nolan Batman doesn't belong in any other movies. (This quote can be interpreted as purely his opinion)

> The actor reflected that, though he thinks that The Dark Knight is a "character that could have kept on going and going and going," that ultimately, "it was right for Chris [Nolan] to finish it where he did."
>
> Adding, "And ours doesn't belong in any other version at all."

Comment: Batman and Superman are the "most mythological superheroes"?  I assume he must be talking about just DC, because I think Thor has them beat (being literally a mythological figure).

Comment: @Darrel Thor comes from ancient mythology. Batman and Superman are part of a modern mythology.

Comment: Note the word "our" this is DC universe specific

Answer (score -1):

The state of what DC movies are continuity with the others are... a difficult subject.

Nolan's Batman was supposed to be canon with Superman Returns, but that didn't work out so was dropped and then it was later supposed to be Canon with Green Lantern, but it flopped so they decided to nope that. Then DC with Man of Steel and it was also supposed to be canon with Nolan's Batman, along with Green Lantern, but by the time Man of Steel was finished being mad Nolan had made it clear that Superman doesn't exist in Nolan's Batman and various other things which resulted in Man of Steel and Nolan's Batman not being in the same canon.

If Nolan's Batman was part of MoS and BvS canon then Batman Begins would take place 20 years previous and Dark Knight Returns would take place 10 years previous to BvS. That's a big enough leap to have it be in the same canon if they really wanted to, but I prefer it not be, because Nolan's Batman is not Batman. His character is completely off from what Batman's character in the comics is.

Comment: Do you have any sources for these?

Comment: Unfortunately, nope this is all just 1 from what I can recall about talks around these films years ago and 2 there is youtube video, I can't find, pointing out that the current cinematic universe the 3rd or 4th attempted at getting one going and laying it all out.

Answer (score -4):

Maybe only was a easter egg, but a satellite that Zod and Kal destroy in "Man of Steel", bears the same "Wayne Enterprises" logo, that it was seen in Nolan´s movies.

In my opinion, I think that there is a simple thinking or wishing, from Warner/DC, to make Nolan's Dark Knight as the beginning of the DC Extended Universe, because the critical acclaim received for that films it would to legitimize that world. But against that wish is the voice from Nolan himself, that years ago established his films as a closed story.