# Is there any connection between Ra's al Ghul from Batman and ArrowVerse?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, nolan-batman-trilogy, arrow, batman-begins

In Batman Begins, Ra's al Ghul is Bruce's mentor and Batman leaves him to die, we're not sure if he dies. And if he dies he could be brought back with the Lazarus Pit.

In the Arrowverse, Merlyn also has Ra's al Ghul as his mentor. Ra's wants Oliver to take over his role as Head of the Demon, Oliver kills Ra's and hereby becomes the new Ra's al Ghul. He then gives the position to Malcolm Merlyn.

What is the synchronicity between these character?
Are they in the same timeline, the same person or do they lives in another universe (in the multiverse that we get to know in the Flash)?

I haven't read any of the comics, I saw the Christopher Nolan Batman movies, the Arrow, the Flash and Supergirl.

I read the following links but they didn't made it clear to me:

[ComicVine](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/ras-al-ghul/4005-40816/)

[Arrow wikia](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Ra%27s_al_Ghul_(title))

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ra%27s_al_Ghul)

Comment: Related question from sister site [Who killed Ra's Al Ghul first, Batman or Arrow?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42004/who-killed-ras-al-ghul-first-batman-or-arrow)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Ra's al Ghul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ra%27s_al_Ghul) is a popular DC antagonist, like any character in such a franchise he will see different incarnations in different universes.

I think the crux of your question is "Are the Nolan Batman films in the Arrowverse"

From a brief check I believe not, [Arrowverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowverse) seemed to start with the TV series The Arrow, and revolves around mostly TV series and webcomics. This list is not exhaustive but should cover most aspects of the Arrowverse

- Arrow (2012)
- The Flash (2014)
- Vixen (2015)
- Supergirl (2015)
- Legends of Tomorrow (2016)
- Freedom Fighters: The Ray (2017)

The Nolan movies seem to sit in their own continuity ([more or less](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124710/is-the-dark-knight-trilogy-part-of-the-same-dc-cinematic-universe-as-man-of-st)).

So while the characters are the same person, they are not the same instance of the same person.  Obviously, the creators of the Arrowverse are able to incorporate whatever backstory they want.

It should be noted, that I have found DC Universes to be a little more porous than Marvel ones, so you may find that when it suits the creators they can be the same, and you will have to ignore any wild inconsistencies this will cause.

Comment: Can you provide the answers here instead of simply linking to other places. Makes it a slightly better answer. If I took away everything but those links I'd get the same answer (barring the first "paragraph"/sentence)

Comment: I'm using the links to provide context. If you remove the links you have a complete answer, explaining the crux of the question and why they are different universes.

Comment: If you remove the links you have a bunch of words speculating that they’re different. While it’s clear they are, providing some of the details from the links improves your answer.

Comment: [In this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ra%27s_al_Ghul#Live_action) they state that Liam Neeson wanted to replay the part for Ra's al Ghul in Arrow but wasn't able due to scheduling issues. If he would have played the part that would have made it really confusing